# Laravel Error: Call to a member function create() on null

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I need your help. I am learning **Laravel** and I know it has been asked many times, but can't make it work.

I am trying to save a category with a `page_id`.

My `store` method in **CategoryController** looks like this:

```
public function store(Page $page){

    $data = request()->validate([
        'title' => 'required'
    ]);

    $category = $page->categories()->create($data);

    return redirect('/category/' . $category->id);
}
```

My Page `model` looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function categories() {
        $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

My category `migration` looks like this:

```
 public function up()
   {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('page_id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
   }
```

I would like to understand first what I am doing **wrong**.

Thank you,
Cheers

Comment: The code you've posted shouldn't be able to throw that error. `$page->categories()`, if configured properly, should return a `Relationship`, and a `hasMany()` shouldn't return `null` (it can return a empty one, but that's not `null`). Do a `dd($page->categories())` and see what that returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your categories relation must returned the hasMany object.
change code to this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function categories() {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it was missing the return keyword. 
It is working now.